# Android Google map custom view

Tags: android, google-maps, canvas, android-mapview

My client wants his google map to be initially hidden and gradually get visible as  a user walks around on it with a 15m radius. I have searched and searched but couldnt find anything useful. Can someone please point me to some resource or tutorial that can help me achieve this? Can I overlay an opaque canvas and have it become transparent as the user moves?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is in essence similar to minimaps that we see in age of mythoology, warcraft, etc.

Comment: you have no control when or how maps tiles are loaded

Comment: so im guessing that is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the alpha state of the map view from 0 to 1 as you receive gps coordinates.

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29
```

There is a certain amount of Jitter involved in GPS coordinates so your map would gradually become visible even if you did not move around.

ALternatively, you could lay a view over the map with RelativeLayout and gradually change the alpha state of the overlay.